# refreshing UIView in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, refresh

hii every one ,

in my iphone application am downloading a image(jpg) file from FTP & loading that to the footer of every screen,& am placing following code in `viewDidLoad` to assign the file to image variable

```
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XML"];
   documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Extras"];
   imgLogo.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo.jpg"]];
```

but image is not displaying when we open the screen for first time it will be loaded after reopening the same screen 2 ,3 times,,so i need to refresh the view ,,,how can i do that?? can any one help me,,,,thanx in advance

Comment: Put your code into ViewDidAppear Method or set [self.view setNeedsDisplay];(Redraw your view) for refreshing the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try

```
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Quote from Apple docs:

`By default, geometry changes to a view automatically redisplays the view without needing to invoke the drawRect: method. Therefore, you need to request that a view redraw only when the data or state used for drawing a view changes.In this case, send the view the setNeedsDisplay message. Any UIView objects marked as needing display are automatically redisplayed when the application returns to the run loop.`

Comment: then i think the image is not yet available or does not exist at that point of time in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to incomplete download
Please write code to check whether the file exists at that location or not. 
Also you can append path in one line
documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XML/Extras/Logo.jpg"];

Comment: ya file is downloading to the folder,,,but for first time image is not displaying,,but it will  be loaded upon re opening the same screen